# Use Of Ajax - for opening a file ans showing its contents on webpage asynchronously

Tags: ajax

I am redirecting output of some unix commands say ls -a >> test.txt to  the file named test.txt.
Now I need to open this file and show the contents on the browser asynchronously as the user executes the commands on clients side . I need to append the contents of this file on webpage by continously polling the  server  . I am new to ajax . How do we open the file and obtain contents so that they can be displayed ?
Please explain with some example . my application server is Django
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be performing a http GET on the file in question.  Just look up absolutely any article about how to implement simple AJAX.  Examples abound.  Use the Google.